# getting all files with specific format in a domain

Tags: php, dns, server

i am trying to make a project that works this way:
there is a text box to give a list of domains
then php file will get all the files in whole the domain with specified format for example .img and will list the urls and when you click download it will download it
so main question is that is there any way to list the files of a domain? in all folders and categories
Thanks

Comment: No, this is generally _not_ possible, except if the http server handling the domain actually published file lists. However that is not common, since it is considered a huge security issue, except is very special situation. You simply do not have the information available that you need to implement your service.

Comment: so what the domain should be like in settings to publish its files? i mean in the servers

Comment: The only possible approach would be to do a domain specific google search (possible), then parse each single hit you get in the result to find all existing references to files you are interested in. However there are a few issues with that: 1. it is extremely slow and inefficient, 2. it will usually be considered miss usage (thus your robot will be blocked) and 3. this will certainly _not_ provide a complete list of files, but only a list of files you could find from the outside.

Comment: This has nothing to do with domains or "domain settings". All http server implementations offer some index feature to list files contained in a folder. If that is enabled it publishes a list of files in a folder. If it is enabled for all folders that should result in a list of all files. But as said: you won't find servers that open. So it is nothing that helps, it is a theoretical option. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: so assuming that we have access to servers and can enable this.. then it is possible to do it remotely right?

Comment: Well if the feature is enabled then you can see a list of files remotely, yes. If you can retrieve those files obviously also depends on the authorization scheme the server applies ("permissions"). And obviously this will only show files in the folders published and only physical files, so no images created on the fly as many services do these days. Apart from that: you will see a list of files and you certainly can present that list in your planned service. However consider the hint about miss usage I made in my second comment and its potential consequences. We are talking law here.